# how can recognize that member X has added user Y (new member to group) in a telegram group by a telegram bot with admin permission in group?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

how can recognize that each member in a telegram group has added how many user to group by a telegram bot with admin permission in group?
i couldn't do that with [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).
is there any plugin that make it possible?
i am developing the bot in C# programming language.
any help appreciated !.

Answer (score 1):

Since API didn't provide many matrices, you have to log `.message.new_chat_members` by yourself.